# Align gridlines for multiple scales in anychart

Tags: anychart

I have an anychart chart with 2 Y-axes with their own scales.
For both scales the gridlines are active.
The number of gridlines for both axes differ (see attached example image).
Is it possible to align the gridlines for both Y-axes?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVqxE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should enable grid lines on your chart with [`yGrid()`](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.charts.Cartesian#yGrid) and tweak the configuration of your vertical scales, especially **ticks intervals**.

Here is an example:

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(() => {
  let data1 = [
    ["A", 7],
    ["B", 3]
  ];
  
  let data2 = [
    ["A", 112365],
    ["B", 99986]
  ];

  let chart = anychart.column(),
      series1 = chart.column(data1),
      series2 = chart.column(data2);
  
  let yScale = chart.yScale();
  yScale.minimum(0);
  yScale.ticks().interval(2); // <--- HERE
  
  let extraYScale = anychart.scales.linear();
  extraYScale.minimum(0);
  extraYScale.ticks().interval(40000); // <--- HERE
  
  let yAxis = chart.yAxis(0);
  yAxis.stroke("red");
  yAxis.ticks().stroke("red");
  yAxis.labels().fontColor("red");

  let extraYAxis = chart.yAxis(1);
  extraYAxis.scale(extraYScale);
  extraYAxis.orientation("right");
  extraYAxis.stroke("green");
  extraYAxis.ticks().stroke("green");
  extraYAxis.labels().fontColor("green");
  
  series1.yScale(yScale);
  series2.yScale(extraYScale);
  
  series1.normal().fill("red", 0.5);
  series1.normal().stroke("red", 1);
  series2.normal().fill("green", 0.5);
  series2.normal().stroke("green", 1);
  
  chart.yGrid(true); // <--- HERE
  chart.container("container");
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-cartesian.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```